# detached entity on flush

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am getting bellow exception. I am using a spring-data , JPA && Hibernate
I have a method which does some updates to some entities and queries.
Before the transaction finishes and before calling myRespositoryEntity.save(myEntity) , I guess because of keeping consistency in the transaction , hibernate/jpa executes a flush, and on this flush it looks like it tries to do an persist instead of a merge.
I am aware I have some detached entities , but What does this exception occur when flushing and not saving ? If I try to save the entity early in the transaction, exception does not occur.

I have detached entities because I convert from DTOs to Entities objects and some existing objects are not placed in the entity manager. But If I did not get this random flush behaviour , merge would do things right

Any workaround ? Any Ideas?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: package.MyEntity
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:838)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 130 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate uses `FlushMode.AUTO` as the default and this is why you observe this behavior.

Basically when `FlushMode.AUTO` is set, Hibernate will check if any entity state in the session is dirty prior to executing any query operation.  If dirty state is detected, it may opt to flush the state so that those changes will be reflected in the query results.

As a side note, Hibernate does have some optimizations to avoid always flushing should the query you're executing not have any dirty entity state which would influence the results

You can disable this behavior by changing the flush mode type to `COMMIT`.  This basically will cause Hibernate not to flush any database changes until the transaction commits.  This may have some undesired side affects based on your usage, so be forewarned.

If it's possible, I would suggest leaving the `FlushMode` alone unless absolutely necessary and optimize your repository code such that you gather all entity state from the database prior to persisting or merging entities if you can.